# How do I add media files to QMediaPlaylist?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner for Qt and C++ and  making a sample media player. I just want create a playlist with using QMediaplaylist class.

I just want it so that when I click a icon, it pops up a window where I can select multiple video files, appending those files with QMediaplaylist.

I have done the multiple selection part. But I could not work out how to append those file with QMediaPlaylist.

```
playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,"Open a File","","Video File(*.*)");
playlist->addMedia(filenames); //error has occurred in this line 
player->setPlaylist(playlist);
on_actionPlay_triggered();
```

Semantic Issue

```
  error:no matching member function for call to 'addMedia"
  qmediaplaylist.h:90:10:note:candidate function not viable:no known 
  conversion from 'QStringList' to const QMediaContent' for 1st argument 

  qmediaplaylist.h:91:10:note:candidate function not viable:no known 
  conversion from 'QStringList' to 'const QList<QMediaContent>'for 1st 
  argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert each path in `QMediaContent` using `QUrl::fromLocalFile()`:

```
playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, "Open a File","","Video File(*.*)");
for(const QString & filename: filenames){
    playlist->addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename)));
}
player->setPlaylist(playlist);
```